# Test servlet and filter with jUnit and Spring

Tags: java, spring, servlets, model-view-controller, integration-testing

I want to do some integration test for testing servlet context (custom filters and servlets) using jUnit.

The scenario is as follow:
Browser make request to the server to find user. First, the request go thought AuthenticationFilter. When the request path is correct then go to LogginServlet where I try to found information about some user and return it to the browser.

I try to test it with MockMvc. I can add filter to MockMvc (which is executed correctly) but I cannot add servlet, which wolud be called after filter. I try diffrent ways to make servlet managed by spring but I cannot configure it in correct way.

Can anyone help me to make this integration test working? I just want to filter and servlet work together in such scenario.

Test code:

```
public class MockMvcSecurityIT {

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext context;

@Before
public void initMocks(){
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).addFilter(new AuthenticationFilter(), "/*").build();
}

@Test
public void stage10_firstRequestForLoginPageShouldReturnProperPageWithoutCreateingSession () throws Exception {

     MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(get("/login"))
                                    .andDo(print())
                                    .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

}
```

Filter class:

```
@WebFilter(
        urlPatterns = "/*",
        dispatcherTypes = {DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD}
)
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}

    @Override
    public void destroy() {}

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        // business logic to verify request


    }
}
```

Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(
        name = "LoginServlet",
        urlPatterns = {"/login"}
)
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    public LoginServlet() {}

    @Autowired
    public LoginServlet(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext (this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

        // business logic to find and return user

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the TestContext framework in Spring is using a TestDispatcherServlet behind the scenes and I cannot configure or register additional Servlets. There is a link to issue:

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10199

I need to find other way to test my servlet context.

EDIT:

The best solution seems to be EmbeddedTomcat and HttpUnit for example.

Comment: Hi, may I ask if you found a solution to the problem? {{MockMvc}} is a really good option for REST but is there something similar for servlets? Thanks!

Comment: Hi, sorry, I haven't found